# A confusion about Grothendieck universe

Tags: set-theory

Is the "collection of all sets","the collection of all sets of sets"...(and so on) all is a member of a Grothendieck universe?Since the word "set" in Grothendieck universe confused me.And can I extend this forever to abitrary ordinal number?Furthermore,is any Grothendieck universe is an inaccessiable cardinals?

Comment: I know nothing about Gröthendieck universe, but the expresion "the collection of all sets of sets" is the same as "the collection of all sets". Remember that, besides the empty set, any set is a "set of sets".

Comment: @sufronausea Even the empty set is a set of sets - all of its elements are sets! :P

Comment: the collection of all sets is proper class in ZF,but the collection of all classes is meaningless in ZF.My question is that whether or not the hierarchy I mentioned above is a set in Grothendieck universe?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely certain what you are asking, but the following is too long for a comment. Please let me know whether it answers your question and if it doesn't, please try to clarify your post.

Let $U$ be a Grothendieck universe. Now consider the class $V^U$, i.e. the class of which $U$ thinks it contains all sets. $V^U$ is not an element of $U$, but it is a set and hence an element of our background universe. Furthermore, suppose that we have two Grothendieck universes $U_0$ and $U_1$. It is always the case that $U_0 \in U_1$ or $U_1 \in U_0$. Let's say $U_0 \in U_1$ and consider $V^{U_{0}}$. As above, this is a class in $U_{0}$ that is not a member thereof. But it is a member of $U_1$.

I have no idea what you're trying to do in your recursive construction of the set of all sets of all sets ... In each case that's just $V$ - the class of all sets. But we can build this class in different universes - our Grothendieck universes and our background universe for example.

Finally, it's easy to see that the existence of a Grothendieck universe is equivalent to the existence of an inaccessible cardinal: If $U$ is a Grothendieck universe, then $U = V_{\kappa}$ for some inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$. Conversely, if $\kappa$ is inaccessible, then $U := V_{\kappa}$ is a Grothendieck universe.

In the same spirit we can show that the existence of $\alpha$ Grothendieck universes is equivalent to the existence of $\alpha$ inaccessibles. Nonetheless,  the existence of a proper class of Grothendieck universes is quite weak: E.g. if $\kappa$ is Mahlo, then 
$$
V_\kappa \models \text{ there is a proper class of Grothendieck universes.}
$$